# Using special characters with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to replace text in a nav with jQuery.
I know how to do the replacement, but some of my type has Spanish and French language accent marks.
Does anyone know a reference to converting them to encoding for JS?
This is my code:

```
var d = $('.navItem3');
d.text(d.text().trim().replace(/Where/i, "D&oacute;nde"));
```

With ó being the o with an accent.
I tried %B3

Comment: You should use `html` method instead of `text`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `html` method instead of the `text` method.

```
$('.navItem3').html(function(i, oldHTML){
   return $.trim(oldHTML).replace(/.../gi, "...");
});
```

Note that IE8 and below do no support the `trim` method, you can use jQuery `$.trim` utility function instead.

Comment: Thank you that works! Is the method you show the method that works with IE8? also I will have multiple replacements, is it possible to do it in the same function?

Comment: @wgoodman You are welcome, yes it works in IE8 and below, `html` method iterates through all of the selected elements, you can change the selector and it will replace all the characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the html entity `&oacute;`, then you should change the call to `.text()` to `.html()` as  @undefined suggests.

You can also use the unicode representation of the ó character, which is `\u00F3`, and keep using `.text()`. You would use `"D\u00F3nde"` for the string.

You should even be able to just use the `ó` character directly and use `"Dónde"` for the string. You just have to paste it into your code if you can't type it directly.

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/wJKph/)

Comment: @wgoodman - You are welcome. You should accept an answer and/or upvote an answer if it is helpful. It looks like you have asked a few questions and said thanks, but have not accepted any answers or upvoted them.